# Python Recursive binary search to find misspelled words

Tags: python, search, text, recursion, binary

I am trying to use a recursive binary search to go through a text file to find and print the misspelled words based upon a dictionary text file. The program prompts you to open a text file which is then read into a list, with each item being an individual word (wordList). If the word is found in the dictionary and spelled correctly, I simply want to pass over it. My code is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

with open("dictionary.txt") as f:
    dictionary = f.read().splitlines()
    dictionary.sort

fileToReadFrom = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
fin = open(fileToReadFrom, "r")
content = fin.read()
wordList = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", content)

def isWordinDictionary():
    left = 0
    right = len(dictionary)-1
    for i in range(len(wordList)):
        while right >= left:
            middle = (left+right)//2
            if dictionary[middle] == wordList[i]:
                return True
            elif dictionary[middle] < wordList[i]:
                left = middle+1
            elif dictionary[middle] > wordList[i]:
                right = middle - 1
            elif left > right:
                print wordList[i]
        isWordinDictionary()
```

The program will run but causes python to not respond. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using 64 or 32 bit Python?  If you're using 32 bit, try checking out [this](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/api/enchant.checker.html)

Comment: What happens when the word isn't in the dictionary? I notice that there's no `return False` anywhere in the function.

Comment: Why are you using a `list` (called dictionary) instead of a `set`?  That would take you from O(Mlog(N)) to O(M) where M is the number of words in the file and N is the number of words in the dictionary.  The code would also be a lot simpler.

Comment: Your bisection algorithm has several issues, the largest of which is that you never `return` your recursive call.  Also, unless you're doing this to teach yourself how to code a binary search (and there are far better examples for doing that), you should just be using a `set`, as @mgilson says.

Comment: Oh, and if you *are* trying to learn binary search (kudos), but you need to make sure that the input is sorted.  `dictionary.sort()`, not `dictionary.sort` won't sort anything until you actually call it.  :)

Comment: Just in case you don't know about it yet, the python includes functionality for binary search through the `bisect` module

Comment: I am (unfortunately) trying to learn binary search which is why I am using list, but thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The first reason `isWordinDictionary()` will never return:

With every recursive call to `isWordinDictionary()` left is reset to `0`, right is reset to `len(dictionary)-1`.

In other words, this only ever returns if the word you are looking for happens to be at index `(len(dictionary)-1)//2`.

The second reason `isWordinDictionary()` will never return:

You should move the for loop out of your function definition. With each recursive call, it starts searching for each word in the wordlist, from the beginning.

You want something like this:

```
def isWordinDictionary(word, left = 0, right = len(dictionary)-1):
    while right >= left:
        middle = (left+right)//2
        if dictionary[middle] == word:
            return True
        elif dictionary[middle] < word:
            left = middle+1
        elif dictionary[middle] > word:
            right = middle - 1
        elif left > right:
            print word
    return isWordinDictionary(word, left, right)

for word in wordList:
    isWordinDictionary(word)
```

Comment: you're going to want that last line of `isWordInDictionary` to `return` the recursive call.